# ElasticSearch 8: is there a "conf.d" folder to change settings without editing elasticsearch.yml?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to edit a few ElasticSearch 8 settings (for example: `network.host`), but I don't want to edit `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` directly. What I'd like to do is to **add my settings to my own file** and put it in an hypothetical `/etc/elasticsearch/conf.d` folder, do be included automatically.

This approach is widespread with multiple other software I use (Nginx, Apache, MySQL, PHP just to name a few).

ElasticSearch already does what i need with `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options.d`, but that folder is just for the the JVM options, not for ES own settings.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the config path via env variables:

`ES_PATH_CONF=/path/to/my/config ./bin/elasticsearch`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/settings.html

There is an old discussion about doing what you are asking about but didn't make it this way:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11362